# Load Images from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote the code below, I can load each image of a column within a individual div, someone could help me adapt the code so that it opens all images within the same div?

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bravo");
$res=mysql_query("select * from coisas");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    echo "<div>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row["imagem"]; ?>"> <?php echo "</div>";

}
?>
```

Comment: move the div element outside the while statement :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bravo");
$res=mysql_query("select * from coisas");
echo "<div>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    echo "<img src=".$row["imagem"].">";

}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bravo");
$res=mysql_query("select * from coisas");

echo "<div>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>

 <img src="<?php echo $row["imagem"]; ?>"> 
<?php 
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("bravo");
    $res=mysql_query("select * from coisas");

?>
<div>
<?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    echo "<img src=\"{$row['imagem']}\">";

    }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    ?> <img src="<?php echo $row["imagem"]; ?>">

<?php 
}
echo "</div>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bravo");

$res = mysql_query("select * from coisas");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)):
?>
    <div><img src="<?php echo $row["imagem"]; ?>"></div>;

<?php endwhile; ?>
```